# How can I use clockwork to input data every hour?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4

My environment is Macbook OSX 10.7 Lion with Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.

I am new to RoR. I built a website with one column database using a scaffold.
It's just a little website about weather.
I want to input degrees to database every hour.
And I found the gem [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork), but I have no idea how to use it with my project.

I wrote `clock.rb` and put it in my project file and ran `rails s` but nothing happened.

Here is myproject/clock.rb

**myproject/clock.rb**

```
require 'clockwork'
module Clockwork

handler do |job|
puts "Running #{job}"

every(1 hours, ''){
Mydata.create(:degree => input_data)
}
end
```

What should I do with it or where should I put the file?

They say that I need to use `$ clockwork clock.rb`, but when I run `rails s`, there's no way to use that...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know why they gave you a -1, but I'll try to answer to your question, even if it's really late :)

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [official docs](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) you need a couple of things.

1. setup the clock file, I've set it in `app/clock.rb`

   require 'clockwork'
     module Clockwork

   ```
   handler do |job|

     case job
     when 'weather.input_degree'
       Mydata.create degree: input_data
     # when 'some_other_task'
     #   ...
     else
       puts "Couldn't find your job!"
     end

   end

   every(1.hour, 'weather.input_degree') # the string indicates an arbitrary job name
   # every(20.seconds, 'weather.some_other_task')
   ```

   end
2. The starting process. The key is to use something like [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman)

   $ gem install foreman

Create a file named `Procfile` in root of your app:

```
web: bundle exec rails -s
clock: bundle exec clockwork app/clock.rb
# any_other_service_you_want: bash script here
```

1. start your server

   $ foreman start

Answer (score 1):

### Add to Gemfile ­

`gem 'clockwork'`

## after adding upper listed gem in gemfile, use bundle install to add this gem into project.

Example ­

Create a file clock.rb under /lib directory

clock.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot', __FILE__)

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

require 'clockwork'

include Clockwork

module Clockwork

## Here Student is a domain class, having a method insertRecord to

## insert a record in DB

every(20.seconds, 'job ­ Inserting Record in DB') { Student.insertRecord }

end
```

Command to Run the clockword

```
bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

This code needs stay outside of handler block:

```
every(1.hour, ''){ Mydata.create(:degree => input_data) }
```

You can execute the clock like that:

```
bundle exec clockwork clock.rb
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of [Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Write a rake task and call the rake task from the Cron for repeating processes.

Example (Add this to cron to run the task every hour):

```
0 * * * * cd /home/projectdir;rake do:task
```

Comment: That's really the suggested way to do it modern application development. More on: http://adam.heroku.com/past/2010/4/13/rethinking_cron/

Comment: question is about `clockwork` gem. your answer is not really answers the question. because Cron is not useful in distributed systems.